# SwiftMessage Regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have the below message:

```
{1:F01ANZBDEF0AXXX0509036846}{2:I103ANZBDEF0XXXXN}{4::20:TEST000001:23B:CRED:32A:141117EUR0,1:33B:EUR1000,00:50A:ANZBAU30:59:ANZBAU30:71A:SHA-}{5:{CHK:1DBBF1D81EE1}{TNG:}}
```

And i want it to be converted like below, with whitespaces in block 4 (which is

```
{4: :20:TEST000001 :23B:CRED :32A:141117EUR0,1 :33B:EUR1000,00 :50A:ANZBAU30 :59:ANZBAU30 :71A:SHA -}
```

---

```
{1:F01ANZBDEF0AXXX0509036846}{2:I103ANZBDEF0XXXXN}{4: :20:TEST000001 :23B:CRED :32A:141117EUR0,1 :33B:EUR1000,00 :50A:ANZBAU30 :59:ANZBAU30 :71A:SHA -}{5:{CHK:1DBBF1D81EE1}{TNG:}}
```

I tried to extract using groups and then apply regular expression. But, i was unsuccessfully. Unable to find the error i am making.

```
public static void StringReplace() {
    String data = "{1:F01ANZBDEF0AXXX0509036846}{2:I103ANZBDEF0XXXXN}{4::20:TEST000001:23B:CRED:32A:141117EUR0,1:33B:EUR1000,00:50A:ANZBAU30:59:ANZBAU30:71A:SHA-}{5:{CHK:1DBBF1D81EE1}{TNG:}}";

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(({1:\\w+})({2:\\w+})({4::\\d+:\\w+:\\d+.:\\w+:\\d+.:\\d+\\w+,\\d:\\d+.:\\w+,\\d+:\\d+.:\\w+:\\d+:\\w+:\\d+.:\\w+-})({5:{\\w+:.\\w+}{\\w+.}}))");

    Matcher m = pat.matcher(data);

    if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
}
```

Thanks in Adavance

Comment: Can you precisely tell what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi: Hi Pushpesh. I want the block 4( which this section -> {4: :20:TEST000001 :23B:CRED :32A:141117EUR0,1 :33B:EUR1000,00 :50A:ANZBAU30 :59:ANZBAU30 :71A:SHA -}) to be seperated by whitepaces. I get the original message without any spaces. If u see my comment above. You will find the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just matched the string and simply printed it but havn't put logic of introducing a space in between. You need to add the logic of introducing space in block 4.

Looking at the expected output of your block 4, you can first catch the block 4 using this regex,

```
(.*?)(\\{4.*?\\})(.*?)
```

and then replace colon with a space colon ( :) in group 2 content which you call as block 4. I see you are not introducing space with every colon instead just for colon which are followed by 2-3 characters followed by colon. I have implemented the logic accordingly in my `replaceAll()` method.

Here is the modified java code,

```
public static void StringReplace() {
    String data = "{1:F01ANZBDEF0AXXX0509036846}{2:I103ANZBDEF0XXXXN}{4::20:TEST000001:23B:CRED:32A:141117EUR0,1:33B:EUR1000,00:50A:ANZBAU30:59:ANZBAU30:71A:SHA-}{5:{CHK:1DBBF1D81EE1}{TNG:}}";

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(.*)(\\{4.*?\\})(.*)");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(data);

    if (m.find()) {
        String g1 = m.group(1);
        String g2 = m.group(2).replaceAll(":(?=\\w{2,3}:)", " :");
        String g3 = m.group(3);
        System.out.println(g1 + g2 + g3);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Didn't match");
    }
}
```

This prints the following output as you expect,

```
{1:F01ANZBDEF0AXXX0509036846}{2:I103ANZBDEF0XXXXN}{4: :20:TEST000001 :23B:CRED :32A:141117EUR0,1 :33B:EUR1000,00 :50A:ANZBAU30 :59:ANZBAU30 :71A:SHA-}{5:{CHK:1DBBF1D81EE1}{TNG:}}
```

Comment: Hi Pushpesh. Yes the code is incomplete. I was not able to get the pattern right. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @JKB: Hope my solution worked for you and if it did, then consider marking it as accepted answer. In case you are having any issues, then let me know.